# Разные spring-конфигурации для продакшена и для дева при сборке maven

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, maven, jboss

Для конфигурирования датасорса использую два класса с аннотацией `@Configuration`. Собираю проект мавеном. Как указать мавену, чтобы он в профиле продакшен брал один датасорс класс, а для дева другой?

**UPD:** в wildfly в файле standalone.conf указываю `-Dspring.profiles.active=production`, при запуске сервера вижу, что опция прописана в java_opts, затем деплою приложения и нажимаю enable, операция падает с ошибкой
`org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.pojo.\"org.jboss.netty.internal.LoggerConfigurator\".DESCRIBED is already registered"}}`

Comment: Мне в голову приходит только создание двух версий конфигов, активируемых через профили по activation условию.
Подробнее - тут: https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/27207/
Сам так не делал, скажу честно.

Comment: Используйте [Spring Profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как посоветовал товарищ @enzo - воспользуйтесь [Spring Profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)

Там все предельно просто - навешиваете аннотацию с именем профайла на конфиг и указываете профиль либо при запуске(предпочтительней), либо указанием через web.xml, как рассказывает вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420745/how-to-set-spring-active-profiles-with-maven-profiles) товарищ @ZNK-M.

Comment: При запуске maven билда? Я навесил аннотации @Profile на свои конфиги.Они синхронизируются с maven профилем?

Comment: Когда я запускаю mvn clean install -Pproduction, все равно появляется ошибка при деплое

Comment: @cadmy профили спринга не имеют ничего общего с профилями мавена и никак с ними не связаны. но можно указать нужный профиль в web.xml и при мавеновском билде подсовывать web.xml с нужными профилями. т.е. имеем dev-web.xml  в котором указан активным профилем dev, prod-web.xml в котором активным профилем указан production, и в момент сборки кладем нужный xml'ник. хотя это вроде как считается bard practice.

Comment: Вы написали "при запуске", при запуске чего вы имели в виду?

Comment: @cadmy при запуске вашего проекта, естественно. параметром запуска, вроде такого  "-Dspring.profiles.active=production"

Comment: как указать профиль при деплое на wildfly без xml?

Comment: @cadmy тут не могу ответить уверенно, но просто mvn clean install wildfly:deploy -Dspring.profiles.active=dev пробовали?

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JVM+settings

Comment: Дописал в standalone.conf в JAVA_OPTS профиль "-Dspring.profiles.active=production"